Is there any possibility to transcode a h264 hls/m3u8 live stream into another HEVC (h265) hls/m3u8 live stream using FFmpeg in real time?
The command I used:
ffmpeg -i  https://tezaurtv.md/wp-content/uploads/live/index.m3u8 -c:v libx265 -b:v 1500k -tag:v hvc1 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 10 -hls_flags delete_segments+append_list+program_date_time -hls_playlist_type event -hls_segment_type mpegts -hls_segment_filename "D:/BRUT/HLS/test/stream_%d.ts" -vsync 2 -rtbufsize 500M -loglevel debug D:/BRUT/HLS/test/stream.m3u8

I tried a lot of commands and parameters but nothing helps. The experiment is on local Windows. Transcode with ffmpeg and play with FFplay.
The problem is the following: After I start stream.m3u8 to play after a few seconds the picture and sound stops. What is wrong in the FFmpeg command?
ffmpeg version 7.0.2-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)

ffplay version 7.0.2-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2003-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)

An error from FFplay:
[hevc @ 0000023d8c320940] Output frame with POC 239.
[hevc @ 0000023d8c320940] Decoded frame with POC 241.
[hevc @ 0000023d8c320e40] nal_unit_type: 35(AUD), nuh_layer_id: 0, temporal_id: 0
[hevc @ 0000023d8c320e40] nal_unit_type: 0(TRAIL_N), nuh_layer_id: 0, temporal_id: 0
[hevc @ 0000023d8c320e40] Output frame with POC 240.
[hevc @ 0000023d8c320e40] Decoded frame with POC 240.
[hevc @ 0000023d855aae80] nal_unit_type: 35(AUD), nuh_layer_id: 0, temporal_id: 0
[hevc @ 0000023d855aae80] nal_unit_type: 0(TRAIL_N), nuh_layer_id: 0, temporal_id: 0
[hevc @ 0000023d855aae80] Output frame with POC 241.
[hevc @ 0000023d855aae80] Decoded frame with POC 242.
[hevc @ 0000023d8c2cab40] nal_unit_type: 35(AUD), nuh_layer_id: 0, temporal_id: 0
[hevc @ 0000023d8c2cab40] nal_unit_type: 1(TRAIL_R), nuh_layer_id: 0, temporal_id: 0
[hevc @ 0000023d8c2cab40] Output frame with POC 242.
[hevc @ 0000023d8c2cab40] Decoded frame with POC 247.
[hevc @ 0000023d8c2da9c0] nal_unit_type: 35(AUD), nuh_layer_id: 0, temporal_id: 0
[hevc @ 0000023d8c2da9c0] nal_unit_type: 1(TRAIL_R), nuh_layer_id: 0, temporal_id: 0
[hevc @ 0000023d8c2da9c0] Output frame with POC 243.
[hevc @ 0000023d8c2da9c0] Decoded frame with POC 245.
[hls @ 0000023d85544b80] Opening 'D:\BRUT\HLS\test\stream.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0000023d85544b80] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0000023d85544b80] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY')
[hls @ 0000023d85544b80] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2024-08-30T16:29:28.175+0300')
[AVIOContext @ 0000023d8c327040] Statistics: 207 bytes read, 0 seeks
[hls @ 0000023d85544b80] Opening 'D:\BRUT\HLS\test\stream.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0000023d85544b80] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')sq=    0B
[hls @ 0000023d85544b80] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY')
[hls @ 0000023d85544b80] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2024-08-30T16:29:28.175+0300')
[AVIOContext @ 0000023d8c326980] Statistics: 207 bytes read, 0 seeks
[hls @ 0000023d85544b80] Opening 'D:\BRUT\HLS\test\stream.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0000023d85544b80] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0000023d85544b80] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY')
[hls @ 0000023d85544b80] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2024-08-30T16:29:28.175+0300')
[AVIOContext @ 0000023d8c326f00] Statistics: 207 bytes read, 0 seeks
  11.30 A-V:-18.499 fd=   3 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B


The issue is in real time. It depends on the CPU, GPU, frame rate and other factors.

I tested on 2 different systems, same result. If I use the command "-hls_playlist_type vod", then the final output is OK. In this case there is a problem and that is that the playlist is not refreshed in real time and is created at the end. So this method is not good for my requirements.
Also I noticed that when I start to play the m3u8 file it immediately creates another one with the same name with the extension "tmp", which seems to me to actually create the problem with the video stopping.

Try using -movflags +faststart, to make it playable right away.
